# How do I create a list of items with equally sized columns in Android

Tags: android, wpf

I want to achieve something like this in Android:

[image: table]

Note that the content is dynamic, so the width of the columns cannot be fixed at compile time. The number of rows is dynamic, however the number of columns is fixed.

In WPF I would use an `ItemsControl` with a `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel`. I would then set the `ItemTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` containing a `Grid` with `ColumnDefinition`s and `SharedSizeGroup`s. Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="MyViewModel" x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col2"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text={Binding Column0} Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text={Binding Column1} Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text={Binding Column2}/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemTemplate={StaticResource MyItemTemplate}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"/>
    </ItemsControl>
</ItemsControl>
```

I cannot figure out how to do it in Android.
I know I have to use a `RecyclerView` (the equivalent of an `ItemsControl`) and a `LinearLayoutManager` (the equivalent of the `StackPanel`). But how do I match up the column sizes in each item?

Comment: number of columns is always 3?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use `RecyclerView`. But as a first step, try with `GridView`:

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Comment: But this means the adapter has to return 3 items per row, doesn't it?